# Ruby + HTML div tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I want to embed some ruby code to adjust the width of a  on my html page.

Basically I have a loop in the Html page which looks like this

```
<% pass_fail.each do |row| %>

<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 70%;"></div>
<div class="bar bar-warning" style="width: 20%;"></div>
<div class="bar bar-danger" style="width: 10%;"></div>

<% end %>
```

I want the width of the divs to be something like

```
((row[1]/(row[1]+row[2]+row[3]))*100)%
((row[2]/(row[1]+row[2]+row[3]))*100)%
((row[3]/(row[1]+row[2]+row[3]))*100)%
```

Can someone please help me with the exact syntax to embed the code to set the width of the div.

Comment: Why not let CSS do it for you? You're already setting a class name.

Comment: I am not sure how I can set something dynamically with the ruby code and CSS

Comment: Unless you need a pile of widths, just use static CSS entries.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html

Comment: I do have 100's of <div> with different widths each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming `row` is a Array of three ints, use `<%=  %>` to output:

```html
<div style="width:<%= ((row[0].to_f / (row[0] + row[1] + row[2])) * 100) %>%">Div 1</div>
<div style="width:<%= ((row[1].to_f / (row[0] + row[1] + row[2])) * 100) %>%">Div 2</div>
<div style="width:<%= ((row[2].to_f / (row[0] + row[1] + row[2])) * 100) %>%">Div 3</div>
```

`to_f` must be used to capture the results since it is between 0 and 1. Can be simplified by summing the array using `inject`:

```html
<div style="width:<%= ((row[0].to_f / row.inject(:+)) * 100) %>%">Div 1</div>
<div style="width:<%= ((row[1].to_f / row.inject(:+)) * 100) %>%">Div 2</div>
<div style="width:<%= ((row[2].to_f / row.inject(:+)) * 100) %>%">Div 3</div>
```

Not really see what you will use this for, but I understand it is spectacular.

Unless the sum of `row` is changing between each iteration, it is recommended to cache the sum where possible to speed up execution.

Answer (score 0):

Let CSS do the work for you:

In your stylesheet:

```
.bar-success {
    width:70%
}
.bar-warning{
    width:20%
}
.bar-danger{
    width:10%
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="bar bar-success"></div>
<div class="bar bar-warning"></div>
<div class="bar bar-danger"></div>
```

Comment: the width of the div changes for every iteration of my ruby code.....I am not sure how I would set that in CSS